# Merge list of duplicate Faceitfields in solr using java

Tags: java, list

I Have a List of Facet fields added in a loop, these loops add all faceits fetched from solr faceit results, which has duplicate entry in final facieit field 'allFacetFields',

```
[
movie-1:[
    manufaturer(10),
    producers(5),
    actors(12)
],
movie-2:[
    manufaturer(10),
    producers(5),
    actors(12)
],
movie-3:[
    manufaturer(10),
    producers(5),
    actors(12)
],
movie-1:[
    manufaturer(3),
    producers(2),
    actors(2)
],
movie-2:[
    manufaturer(4),
    producers(7),
    actors(6)
],
 ]
```

below code gets all faceit fields from solr query from loop and adds into allFacetFields from each facetFieldIterator

```
List<FacetField> allFacetFields = new ArrayList<FacetField>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : coresResult.entrySet()) {
   List<FacetField> coreFacets = respForCores.getFacetFields();
   Iterator<FacetField> facetFieldIterator = coreFacets.iterator();
   while(facetFieldIterator.hasNext()){
    allFacetFields.add(facetFieldIterator.next());
   }
}
```

how to validate duplicate faceit before adding it to final faceit field allFacetFields and merger the results as following :

```
[
movie-1:[
    manufaturer(13),
    producers(7),
    actors(14)
],
movie-2:[
    manufaturer(14),
    producers(12),
    actors(18)
],
movie-3:[
    manufaturer(10),
    producers(5),
    actors(12)
]
]
```

Comment: This is more of a straight Java question than specific to Solr - I'd suggest using a `Map<String, Map<String, int>>` to keep your counts, and then look them up when iterating over the facet values from each core. _If_ the definition of these cores are identical, you can also use Solr's sharding support to make Solr do it for you instead.

Comment: The definition are not same that was he main reason for looping to add distinct faceit, will it convert from faceit to map type ? let me try